# Polymorphic ADT with type-class constrained Constructor

Tags: haskell

Why does the following code fail to compile?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

class Foo x where whoAmI :: x -> Int

data One = One
instance Foo One where
  whoAmI _ = 1

data Two = Two
instance Foo Two where
  whoAmI _ = 2

data Poly f = (Foo f) => Poly { member :: f }
makePoly :: Bool -> Poly f
makePoly what =
  if what == True then Poly { member = One }
  else Poly { member = Two }
```

Obviously, this is a contrived example. In the end, I want to have a record `Poly f` and pass that to other functions like `g :: Poly f -> Int`, where `g` can only interact with it's argument by using the functions given by the class `Foo`.

This is the GHC v8.6.3 compile error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘f’ with actual type ‘One’
‘f’ is a rigid type variable bound by
  the type signature for:
    makePoly :: forall f. Bool -> Poly f
```

Is it at all possible to do something like that? Which extensions (if any) are needed to make it compile?

Comment: I think it's saying that the type signature `Bool -> Poly f` has to work for *all* types `f`, that is there has to be effectively a different possible output for any type you specify. (A bit like how `read` can output any type that is an instance of `Read`.) You are only outputting values of type `Poly One` or `Poly Two` - which I think is illegal in any case. (I'm no expert though, perhaps it is possible to do this with some language extension.) Also the `Foo f` constraint in the data declaration is wrong I believe, that constraint should only be on the functions that require it.

Comment: Put the constraints where they belong - on the functions that actually use them. It pays off in the long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are slightly mixed up about existentials.  What you have written

```
data Poly f = (Foo f) => Poly { member :: f }
```

defines a family of types, e.g. one type `Poly One`, a *different type* `Poly Two`, etc.  When a `Poly` is constructed, its `Foo`-ness is checked.

The problem with

```
makePoly :: Bool -> Poly f
```

is that the *caller* gets to choose `f`.  So

```
makePoly True :: Poly One
makePoly True :: Poly Two
makePoly True :: Poly Elephant
```

all have to work, but your function doesn't work this way.   It seems like you almost know what you're doing, since if instead of defining a family of types you defined a *single* existential type, then this would be fine:

```
data Poly = forall f. (Foo f) => Poly { member :: f }
```

Notice that there is no `f` on the left side of the `=` sign, so this is a single type, not a family.  Therefore a function claiming to return a `Poly` can return any `Poly` it likes.  This definition makes your code work.

Technical note, the `member` field accessor is completely useless, because the return type depends on what *value* is passed in

```
member :: Poly -> ????
```

so it cannot be assigned a type in the Haskell type system (dependent type systems could do it, though).  To use a `Poly` you *must* pattern match:

```
usePoly :: Poly -> Int
usePoly (Poly x) = whoAmI x -- x :: a  for some *unknown* type a in this scope
```

Another note, `Poly` is completely equivalent to `Int`, since if we are given a `Poly x`, all we know about `x` is that it is a `Foo`, and the only thing we can do with a `Foo` is call `whoAmI`.  In cases like this I would just [skip the existential](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) and use `Int`.  But there are valid uses of existentials, they are just a lot less common than people expect.